# BuildFire - How to trigger a push notification from the admin panel using the SDK?

Tags: buildfire

Is there a way to trigger a push notification from inside the admin dashboard using the BuildFire SDK?

I want to be able to send a push notification to specific individuals to inform them of being granted access to a plugin by the admin.

I have looked in the docs and haven't seen anything regarding being able to trigger a push notification from the dashboard with the SDK, or anything about targeting a specific user.

Is this not possible?  If it isn't it would be a great feature to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you currently cannot. This is an item in the backlog. However, there isnt an ETA I can provide. We'll keep an eye out for the up-
votes here.